# footer section height issue in zurb foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a simple page with slider, few images and a footer section.

I want footer section to be full-width and have  min-height of 100px and also take all the available space at the screen. the way i have done it is that it takes more than usual space which add v. scroll bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/8/

```
<div class="row fullWidth">
    <div class="large-12 columns footer"> footer</div>
</div>
```

I am not sure why it is behaving in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this result shown in JSFIDDLE

I have edited your [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/57fBK/19/)

I have done the following things

Remove `height:100%;` from `.fullWidth`

and added `min-height:100%;` to `.footer`

**CSS:**

```
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
.columns {
    float:none !important;
}
.small-6 {
    width:100%;
}
}

 .fullWidth {
     width: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     max-width: initial;
     background-color:red;
 }
.footer
{
   text-align:center;
   min-height:100%;
   margin:20px auto;
 }
}
```

Comment: this is similar to giving direct height 100px to footer, But i want footer height to increase automatically if page is small the the screen height.